# How can I make a upload .txt file form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my codes:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form_id" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="files" class="drop-files-container">drag here</label>
        <input id="files" type="file" name="file[]" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#files').on('change',function() {
    var files = $(this)[0].files;
    processFileUpload(files);
    return false;
});

function processFileUpload(droppedFiles) {
    var uploadFormData = new FormData($("#form_id")[0]);
    if(droppedFiles.length > 0) {
        for(var f = 0; f < droppedFiles.length; f++) {
            uploadFormData.append("file",droppedFiles[f]);
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : "compareList.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : uploadFormData,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$arr = array();
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
```

And my code returns this:

> **Warning**:  fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\comparelist_php\compareList.php** on line **6**
>   {"message":"ERROR","code":1337}

How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't us an array notation in the HTML markup: `name="file[]"`. That creates an array inside the $_FILES super global variable on the server side which is _not_ what you want.

Comment: Moreover, even with `<input name="file" />`, `$_FILES['file']` would still be an array, you'd have to use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: @arkascha that's not the problem since OP select only the first. ( `$(this)[0].files`)

Comment: @roberto06 thank you very much .. I've used `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: @stack : Glad to help, I transformed my comment into an answer and added the relevant bit of the PHP documentation, in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$_FILES['file']` is an array, you have to use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`.

Taken from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) :

> The global `$_FILES` will contain all the uploaded file information.
>   Its contents from the example form is as follows. Note that this
>   assumes the use of the file upload name userfile, as used in the
>   example script above. This can be any name.
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`
>
> - The original name of the file on the client machine.
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['type']`
>
> - The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['size']`
>
> - The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`
>
> - The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['error']`
>
> - The error code associated with this file upload.